# C++ double value losing precision when multiplied?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to create a function to find the square root of a number. For debugging purposes, it has instructions to print current variable values. The function `squareRoot` accepts two arguments, `x` and `t`. It then declares and initializes `n` and `s`. `n` is the amount to add or subtract, halving every time it is used. `s` is what is thought to be the current square root. When running, I can clearly see that `n` is adjusting correctly. However, `s` stops changing when the first four digits are correct. I am using this call in `main()`:

```
cout << squareRoot(1000, 10) << "\n";
```

This should print the square root of 1000 to the nearest tenth, but two weird things happen:

- It doesn't stop at 31.6.
- It stops at 4 digits!

My theory as to why it stops at four digits is this: In multiplying, `s` loses some of its precision. Is this true? If so, can you tell me how to correct it? If not, what is causing this and how can I correct that?

I tried to solve it already by using another variable, `s1`, which would be multiplied and checked. Then `s` would be incremented by `n`, and `s1` synchronized with `s`. This didn't work, so I went back to the original code.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double squareRoot(double x, int t) {
    double s = 0;
    double n = 0.1;
    while ((s*s) <= x) {
            s += n;
            n *= 2;
            cout << n << "\n" << s << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    s -= n;
    // Keep changing until margin of error is reached
    while ((((s*s) - x) < (1/t)) || ((x - (s*s) < (1/t)))) {
        // If too high, lower s
        if ((s*s) <= x) {
            s += n;
            n /= 2;
            cout << "Adding 1/2 of previous n\n";
        }
        // If too low, raise s
        else if ((s*s) >= x) {
            s -= n;
            n /= 2;
            cout << "Subtracting 1/2 of previous n\n";
        }
        cout << s << "\n" << n << "\n\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

I am running Windows 7 64 bit, MSVC++ 2008 Express. Thank you in advance for all answers!

Comment: You should probably look up the Newton-Raphson technique for finding square roots.  It converges extremely fast once it gets close to the correct value (doubling the number of significant digits on each iteration).

Comment: The initial loop is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html Not for the faint of heart, but its aptly titled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unrelated, but your sqrt algorithm can be sped up by using an existing one, such as Newton's Method.

It goes like this:

```
double mySqrt(double x, unsigned long accuracy = 10)
{
   if(x < 0.0)
      return(-1.0);

   double retval = 1.0;

   for(unsigned long rep = 0; rep < accuracy; rep++)
      retval = ((x / retval) + retval) / 2.0;

   return(retval);
}
```

Newton's method also works for cube roots, etc.
For decimal exponents, look up the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: You're welcome. I tried this before, so I thought I might share with you what I found out.

Comment: Woops. I used "/ 2" instead of "/ 2.0". It's corrected now. And thanks to whoever edited it to make the code in a codebox.

Comment: I just found out how to use `cout.precision()` to set more than 6 digits! Thank you very much for this!

Comment: I said earlier I changed it to `/ 2.0` from `/ 2`, but I forgot to... Can you change it to `retval = ((x / retval) + retval) / 2.0;`, so it doesn't cause any trouble in the future (on different compilers, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

It converges to the correct square root, but cout only prints six significant digits by default: 31.xxxx.

Also notice that your termination check does not work because (1/t) will always evaluate to 0 for t>1. Use 1./t instead.

Comment: Hmm... When trying your solution to the termination check problem, my loop never ends. Before, it did end. Also, when printing <code>n</code>, the value is correct, just not for <code>s</code>.

Comment: And how would I go about changing this default of six digits?

Comment: @emasonsbro Loop never ends because it has two problems: see my answer for another one. (it's the case when two bugs in the code compensate each other :))

Answer (score 1):

The reason loop isn't stopping is that loop condition isn't correct. You have

```
while ((current - target < precision) || (target - current < precision)) {
    ...
}
```

But either value `current - target` or value `target - current` will be `<= 0`. And `0 < precision`. Thus you have equivalent of `while (true) {...}` loop.
You need something like

```
while (abs(current - target) > precision) {
    ...
}
```

(don't know exact function for getting absolute value in C++)

**edit**
Just noticed, *hamster3null* wrote about `1/t` before me.

Comment: `fabs()` is the function for absolute value of a double in C, assuming you have `<math.h>` included.  Of course, the question is about C++.

Comment: @Jonathon - meaning you should `#include <cmath>` instead.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, I corrected language and another mistake in the code.

Comment: @Steve: I guess so...I added the C++ rider and didn't go back to fix the `#include`.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I think I will instead just use muntoo's code, as it is faster.